# Lags on specific video running on local server (iOS)

Tags: swift, google-cast

Based on [example project](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios) from google build simple player app for play video on device. Added `GCDWebServer` lib for local streaming. All works fine, except [1 video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LC-6jV1igjF5K8S27aUMtQmPpGuhCQ4k/view?usp=sharing). It is little bit laggy. On other players from AppStore this video was played perfectly.

Here code how I setup `GCKCastContext` and start playing on Chromecast:

```
static func setup() {
    let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: kReceiverAppID))
    options.physicalVolumeButtonsWillControlDeviceVolume = true
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)


    let logFilter = GCKLoggerFilter()
    logFilter.minimumLevel = .error
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().filter = logFilter
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = shared

    shared.sessionManager.add(shared)
}

func generateMediaInfo(url: URL) -> GCKMediaInformation {
    let builder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder(contentURL: url)

    builder.streamType = .live
    if url.isFileURL, let mimeType = mimeTypes[url.pathExtension] {
        builder.contentType = mimeType
    }
    builder.metadata = GCKMediaMetadata(metadataType: .movie)
    builder.mediaTracks = nil
    builder.textTrackStyle = buildTextStyle()

    let mediaInfo = builder.build()
    return mediaInfo
}

func buildTextStyle() -> GCKMediaTextTrackStyle {
    let style = GCKMediaTextTrackStyle.createDefault()
    style.windowType = .roundedCorners
    style.windowColor = GCKColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7)
    return style
}

func playURL(_ url: URL, position: Double = 0) {
    let options = GCKMediaLoadOptions()
    options.playPosition = position

    let url = ChromecastServer.startServer(url.path) // builded with GCDWebServer, returns local server url
    let mediaInfo = generateMediaInfo(url: url!)

    if let client = sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient {
        performAsyncIn(.main) {
            client.loadMedia(mediaInfo, with: options)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I'm not properly respond to `Content-Range` request. Fixed version:

```
server = GCDWebServer()
server?.addHandler(forMethod: "GET", path: "/chromecast_video", request: GCDWebServerRequest.self, processBlock: { (req) -> GCDWebServerResponse? in
    var resp: GCDWebServerFileResponse? = GCDWebServerFileResponse()
    if (req.hasByteRange()) {
        return GCDWebServerFileResponse(file: filePath, byteRange: req.byteRange)
    } else {
        return GCDWebServerFileResponse(file: filePath)
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi @Gralex , i am working to cast local videos from iphone to googlecast and for local host i am using CocoaHTTPServer my asset is successfully exporting on directory and i am able to play in on my local created player AVPLayer. but when i am using same url (http://127.0.0.1:56161/rendered_video2.mp4) to googlecast i am getitng below error .

Comment: Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=30 "Media failed to load" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Media failed to load, gck_detailed_error_code=104}

Comment: i am following this code 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203880/ios-cast-video-to-chromecast-using-photokit